# How to fix add to cart page refresh issue in magento?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, magento

I have created one woocommerce site in magento, I am facing one issue in add to cart page. how to add a product in cart without refreshing the page? . Please suggest.

Comment: Please provide more detail and a piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below extension for ajax add to cart.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajaxcart-3-15606.html

So, please try this and let me know in case of any query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ajax request for add to car withour refreashing the page. 
See the below link for how to customize this functionality.

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/04/magento-add-product-to-cart-ajax/